# How can you find out what has a Service Broker conversation locked?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have a service broker queue with one conversation that is not being processed by anything. However it is not returning anything when I run:

```
RECEIVE TOP(1000) * FROM dbo.QueueName
```

However if I run this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.QueueName
```

I am getting a figure in the thousands. The figure is not changing either. I assume that some process has the Conversation Group locked but is not doing anything with it. How can I tell if this is the case and how can I tell which SPID has the lock?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to system views, sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks and sys.dm_tran_locks should get you where you need to go.  The former is high level "what's my process waiting on" type of stuff.  From that, you can get which SPID(s) are blocking your query.  From that list of SPIDs, you can (if you're interested) query the locks view to see what locks they're holding.  Incidentally, I found that one of either allow_snapshot_isolation or read_committed_snapshot on the database helped with queue locking in a recent engagement.